# Call Php from Swift 3 iOS

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Hello I have update my old swift app in the new version of swift 3, The code was connected to a php page by passing values ​​in post and then returning a json message since I updated the app to swift 3 xcode me from the following errors, How can i fix these errors?

**Error:**

[image]

**Swift Code:**

```
let URL_SAVE_TEAM = "http://localhost/ios-login.php"
    var email:String = "";
    var password:String = "";


    func PrintValue(){

       // print(username);
        //print(password);
    }

    func Login() -> Bool{


        //created NSURL
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_SAVE_TEAM)

        //creating NSMutableURLRequest
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

        //setting the method to post
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        //getting values from text fields


        //creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
        let postParameters = "email="+email+"&password="+password;

        //adding the parameters to request body
        request.HTTPBody = postParameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        //creating a task to send the post request
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                return;
            }

            //parsing the response
            do {
                //converting resonse to NSDictionary
                let myJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                //parsing the json
                if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                    //creating a string
                    var msg : String!

                    //getting the json response
                    msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?

                    //printing the response
                    print(msg)



                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
        //executing the task
        task.resume()

        return false;
    }
```

**Xcode Image of Error:**

[image]

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $ris='Ti rispondo dal server zio';

   echo json_encode($ris);
  //  echo "prova";

?>
```

Comment: In swift 3 apple introduced new classes which doesn't have NS prefix. Like URL instead of NSURL, URLSession instead of NSURLSession etc. Click on that error mark and use the suggested quick fix

Comment: @MidhunMP 
I used code, I get the error "Error parsing date", I also posted the php code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write this more swiftly :)

```
func Login() -> Bool{

//created URL
guard let requestURL = URL(string: URL_SAVE_TEAM) else { return false }

//creating URLRequest
var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)

//setting the method to post
request.httpMethod = "POST"

//getting values from text fields


//creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
let postParameters = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)"

//adding the parameters to request body
request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)

//creating a task to send the post request
let session = URLSession.shared

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
  data, response, error in

  guard error == nil else {
    print("error is \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }

  guard let data = data else {
    print("No data was returned by the request!")
    return
  }

  //parsing the response
  do {
    //converting resonse to NSDictionary
    let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, String?>

    //parsing the json
    guard let parseJSON = myJSON, let msg = parseJSON["message"] as? String else {
      print("Error parsing data")
      return
    }

    //printing the response
    print(msg)

  } catch {
    print(error)
  }

}

//executing the task
task.resume()

return false
```

}

You may think to add a completion handler to your function to handle the login success!

Comment: I tried your code but I got an Error Parsing Date error, how can I fix it?

Comment: The parseJSON["message"] does not exist in your php output, try to edit your $ris variable like this : `$ris['message'] = 'Ti rispondo dal server zio';`